# JavaScript Windows 8 app setInterval() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, setinterval

Basically I have this code in MS Visual studio 2012 for a windows 8  JavaScript+jQuery app.

```
<script>

    window.setInterval(function () {

        var currentx = $(".ball").css("left");
        var currenty = $(".ball").css("top");


        $(".ball").css("top", currentx + 1);
        $(".ball").css("left", currenty + 1);

        //debug
        var time=1;
        $("p.test").text("Has been called " +time);
        var time=time+1;

    }, 100);

</script>
```

Yes, I am using jQuery 2.0

Now I looked at the API's here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp
and here  http://api.jquery.com/css/

My code compiles, but it just is not updating the position of the ball. It appears it is only being called once. If it helps the ball is a DIV element. Maybe windows 8 Apps don't fully support DOM manipulation, or just the Window global variable, I don't really know.

What code would I need to achieve my goal of updating this element of class ball's top and left CSS rules at set intervals?

Comment: Are you using jQuery 2.0? It is the first jQuery version that supports windows store apps.

Comment: Yes, I am using jQuery 2.0

Comment: Are those currentx and currenty variables integers?

Comment: This is Javascript, var can hold anything. Though what is returned by $(".ball").css("top"); is indeed a number as I have tested that myself.  Since it has decimals in it I would call it a float or double if this were Java.

Comment: Btw, that debug system will always print 1, you should move that first 'var time = 1;' before window.setInterval -row and replace 'var time=time+1;' with time++;

Comment: Thanks, for the advice. I didn't see that. I also will show another script, maybe it is in conflict somehow with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.css("left")` and `.css("top")` return a string (e.g. `0px`) and not a number so you need to parse it with `parseInt` otherwise the `currentx + 1` results in e.g. `0px1`

And it looks like it is only called once because `time` is defined and set to 1 in the `setInterval`callback, you need to define and initialize it outside of the callback of `setInterval`.

instead of `.css("left")` you could also think over using `.position().left`.

```
(function() {
    var time=1;
    window.setInterval(function () {

            var currentx = parseInt($(".ball").css("left"),10); 
            var currenty = parseInt($(".ball").css("top"),10);


            $(".ball").css("top", currentx + 1);
            $(".ball").css("left", currenty + 1);

            //debug

            $("p.test").text("Has been called " +time);
            time=time+1;

    }, 100);
})();
```

Comment: Let me try that. Thanks. What does the 10 parameter do for the parseInt, I am curious?

Comment: It Works!, thank you so much. I would give you a useful solution but my rep is too low.

Comment: the `10` is the radix (you should always define it to prevent unexpected behaviour) . this tells the `parseInt` function that the string should be parsed as `decimal`. otherwise if you e.g. would do this `parseInt('010')` it is not clear if it should be parsed as `decimal` or `octal` read this for further details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Great information, thanks! I see the Radix, is telling what base to use in terms of number systems right?

Comment: btw. if you want to do animations don't rely on the interval timer. the value just says: _if it is possible invoke the callback every `x` milliseconds'_. to get smooth animations you always need use the elapsed time between the invokations to check how many pixels the object should be moved.